# Insert node at the begining of a list

Tags: c, list, pointers, insert

I need to insert a node at the beginning on a list, how i do that?

with this code:

```
while(tmp!=NULL){
    printf("__________");
    printf("\nCodigo: %d\n",tmp->code);
    printf("Nombre: %s\n",tmp->name);
    printf("Apellido: %s\n",tmp->last);
    tmp = tmp->next;

};
```

i print the list, and this is what i see:

---

Codigo: 3
Nombre: third
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Apellido: node

---

Codigo: 2
Nombre: secc
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Apellido: node

---

Codigo: 1
Nombre: first
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Apellido: node

*so, if i insert something at the beginnig i should see*

---

Codigo: 3
Nombre: third
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Apellido: node

---

Codigo: 2
Nombre: secc
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Apellido: node

---

Codigo: 1
Nombre: first
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Apellido: node

---

Codigo: 4
Nombre: fourth
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Apellido: node

how i do that? i tried with this:

```
    tmp_aux = lista;// creating an aux list
    while(tmp_aux->next!=NULL){
        tmp_aux->next = tmp_aux;
    }; // i used this becouse the last printed (up) is the first node
    new_aux = (struct nodo* ) malloc(1*sizeof(struct nodo));
    printf("ingrese el codigo: ");
    scanf("%d",&(*new_aux).code);
    printf("ingrese el nombre: ");
    scanf("%s",&(*new_aux).name);
    printf("ingrese el apellido: ");
    scanf("%s",&(*new_aux).last);



    new_aux->next = tmp_aux;// then i put the aux on the next of my new node
    lista = new_aux;// and make my list the new one
```

Comment: Assuming `tmp_aux` is non-null at the beginning of your loop, it will never terminate; `tmp_aux->next = tmp_aux` does not traverse the list, just continually reassigns a value. Maybe you wanted to do `tmp_aux = tmp_aux->next`?

Comment: i tried that but still printing the first node at the bottom of the list; i think the last node i scan should be at the bottom... is that right?

Comment: You example shows inserting at the end of the list not at the beginning. If it were at the beginning the new node would print first not last right? So which is it do you really want - beginning or end of list?

Comment: that is what im trying to do, insert it at the beginning, i think if is the first node will be at the bottom of the printed list right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think the first node should be printed first (in reference to the comments), but that's just semantics I suppose.

All the times I've used linked lists, I've used `head` and `tail` pointers.  The `head` pointer points to the first item in the list, the `tail` points to the last item in the list.  There is some extra bookkeeping required to keep these up-to-date every time you add and remove an item from the list, but I think that is well worth the effort.  Any operation that requires you to iterate over the list (searching for a specific node, printing all the items, etc) is done more simply because you start at the `head` and go to the `tail`.  Something like the following should get you started,, this is not meant to be an all-inclusive program:

```
 static struct nodo *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

 struct nodo* insert_at_head(struct nodo* new_aux)
 {
   if (head == NULL && tail == NULL)
   {
     // our list is empty; any item inserted is both the beginning and end
     head = new_aux;
     tail = new_aux;
     new_aux->next = NULL;  // only 1 item in the list, there is no next element
   }
   else
   {
     // if maintained properly, this should be the only other possibility
     new_aux->next = head;  // new_aux is the new head of the list, so the previous head is now the 2nd item
     head = new_aux;  // make new_aux the new head of the list
   }

   // in fact, since head = new_aux happens in both branches, that should just go here

   return head;  // this could be a void function, but returning head and checking that it equals new_aux shows that new_aux is now the head of the list
 }

 struct nodo* remove_head()
 {
   if (head != NULL)  // our list is not empty, so it does in fact have a head
   {
     struct nodo* temp = head
     head = head->next;  // even if there is one item in the list, head->next should be NULL, so now head is NULL
     free(temp);
   }
   else
   {
     // this means our list is empty, optionally print an error message or warning "Trying to delete head from empty list!"
     return NULL;
   }

   return head;
 }

 // now iterating over all the nodes is easy, you just have to go from head to tail.
 void print_list()
 {
   struct nodo* cur_aux;
   for (cur_aux=head; cur_aux!=NULL; cur_aux=cur_aux->next)
   {
     // print whatever you want here
   }
 }

 // you can have several other functions, for manipulating the list.  Their prototypes *might* look like the following:
 // do not forget to maintain head and tail pointers for all of these!
 struct nodo* insert_at_tail(stuct nodo* new_aux); // similar to insert_at_head(), except now you want to make the current last node the 2nd to last node
 struct nodo* locate_aux(const struct nodo* aux); // iterate head to tail and return the node that matches all fields of struct nodo, return NULL if not found
 void delete_aux(struct nodo* aux); // iterate through the list and delete aux if found
 void clean_up_list(); // iterate from head to tail and delete all items
 struct nodo* insert_aux_after(struct nodo* insert_after, struct nodo* new_aux); // this will insert new_aux after insert_after

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   // something like this
   struct nodo* new_aux = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
   struct nodo* new_aux2 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
   struct nodo* new_aux3 = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

   // fill in the fields for each new_aux
   if (insert_at_head(new_aux) != new_aux)
   {
     // some error happened on insertion,, handle it
   }
   insert_at_head(new_aux2);
   insert_at_head(new_aux3);

   print_list();
   // the output should print new_aux3, then new_aux2, and finally new_aux

   clean_up_list();
   return 0;
 }
```

You can adjust `head` and `tail` to be first or last in the list, but general convention labels `head` as the first item in the list.  I could possibly fill in some code for the other prototypes.  In fact you could implement everything above without a `tail` pointer, just start all your iterations over the list at `head` and go until `->next == NULL`.  You might also consider maintaining a `static size_t num_aux` that keeps a running count of the number of items in the list.  This would especially be helpful for determining success or failure when trying to delete items from the list.  I suspect if you google a tutorial on linked lists you will get far better code than what I provided, but what I showed should be at least one reasonable approach to dealing with linked lists.